# Units of Conductance

Tags: conductivity

I'm trying to understand how conductance that is measured in Siemens is equal 
to Amperes/Volt.

The SI units of Siemens is given to be in $$ kg^{-1}m^{-2}s^3A^2 $$ ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siemens_(unit))). 
I am not sure how this is related to A/V.

Could someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 V is equivalent to 1 joule per coulomb (meaning, it takes 1 J of energy to move 1 C of charge across a potential difference of 1 V).

1 J is \$1\ \rm kg\ m^2\ s^{-2}\$.

1 C is \$1\ \rm A\cdot s\$.

So 1 V is \$ 1\rm\ kg\ m^2\ s^{-3}\ A^{-1}\$

Comment: The joys of dimensional analysis with Rayleigh and Buckingham...